# How to write a Java or Javascript program which organizes data give in alphabetical order?

Tags: alphabetical, organizer

I want to be able to compile and run a java or javascript program which allows me to write words randomly then it assorts them alphabetically. How would this be done? is their any public domain codes that do this?

Thank You

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Javascript's array.sort() method would work fine:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

```
var a = [1, 4, 2, 90, 34];
a = a.sort();
```

I don't know much with java, but it looks like it has a similar thing:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arrays_sort_int.htm

This question has been asked before, by the way, so be sure to do some research before asking.

Answer (score -1):

Create a list of your words and then use  `java.util.Collections.sort(yourList)`